# 1080p not as smooth as 1080i on Sapphire Edge VS4

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, resolution

I have a Sapphire Edge VS4 connected to Philips 37pfl monitor and running Windows 7 32 bit Ultimate. I also use the Catalyst Control Center program to calibrate the screen.

When I choose 1080p resolution I had to adjust the size of the display so it will fit the monitor. After doing that I tested the display by viewing a HD basketball game. The result was rather disappointing - the movement of the players is not smooth.

I have tried 1080i resolution and got a better result. I have used 1080p resolution on this screen with an older HTPC and did not had problems. Am I missing some something in the configuration of the monitor?

Comment: Please, never ever make manual newlines when typing. Computers will do it better than you. You're using fixed-width font when editing, while displaying is usually done with proportional fonts. Manually adjusting line breaks is not necessary and will almost always look terrible when font size or style is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` mode puts less "strain" on your memory bus.
The 'i' stands for `Interlaced` and means that e.g. a 60Hz display gets 30Hz updates for the odd numbered lines and 30Hz for the even numbered lines of the graphics.
Generally: From that it is to be concluded that the display hardware is reading 540 lines of display data out of the RAMs 60 times each second (for a 60Hz display mode). For the 1080p you have more data to read out per second, leaving less time to render/change the data to display; the memory bandwidth becomes a bottleneck.

More about this, e.g:
http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2413044,00.asp
or a google search.